# Have some problems with json deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I get json with russian letters, but without any "":

```
{news: 
[
    {
        document: 
            {
                name: Закон Омской области от 28 апреля 2020 г. N 2269-ОЗ \"О внесении изменений в Закон Омской области \"О бюджете территориального фонда обязательного медицинского страхования Омской области на 2020 год и на плановый период 2021 и 2022 годов\", 
                topic: 7.3965143E7, 
                url: /#/document/73965143
            },

        name: Увеличен объем расходов ТФОМС Омской области на 2020 год,

        paragraphs: 
            [
                В результате изменений общий объем расходов бюджета территориального фонда на 2020 год увеличится на 190,2 млн рублей и составит 28,4 млрд рублей.,
                В связи с образовавшимся превышением расходов бюджета территориального фонда над его доходами утверждены источники финансирования дефицита бюджета территориального фонда на 2020 год., 
                Также уточнены виды (подвиды) доходов бюджета территориального фонда и нормативов распределения доходов между бюджетами бюджетной системы РФ на 2020 год и на плановый период 2021 и 2022 годов.
            ]

    }
]}
```

[I have to split it using these classes](https://www.code.re/nUV)

But i still have a mistake: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 34 path $.news[0]..`

There may be a problem with encoding, but i am not sure. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ty to use Gson lib instead of JSONObject
BTW, the topic was deserealized as a float in sci.notation =  topic: **7.3965143E7**.
That can give you absolutely crazy bugs later.